# Trouble with looking up min value between different conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, min, excel-2016

I am trying to find the minimum time for a fixed date between two different times.
Been trying out different variations but nothing works.

This is on excel 2016, I tried out yesterday with a similar code on a different spreadsheet (a test sheet I created) and it worked. Unfortunately it was on another laptop that I have no longer access to.

Tried out the same code on the sheet I am to use and it did not work.

```
{=MIN(IF((Date<=D5)*(Date>=D4);Time;"");IF((Time<=D7)*(Time>=D6);Time<""))}
{=MIN(IF(;IF((Time<=D7)*(Time>=D6);Time<""))}
```

D5 is the actual date I want to look at (line 1), since it did not work for my I tried out putting an earlier date in D4 but same result (line 2).
D7 and D6 is the end and start time I want to find the value between. 
Tried naming the ranges so Date range refers to the dates (E2:E55220) and Time is the time range I want to find the minimum value in (C2:C55220).

Value I end up with on all attempts is 0

Comment: As far as I can tell, you want: `=MIN(IF((Date<=D5)*(Date>=D4)*(Time<=D7)*(Time>=D6);Time;""))`

Comment: Thanks, that formula makes more sense, but I am still getting the same problem. 
The Date and Time cells refer to a different sheet, might that cause a problem?

I see also that the data it is refering to that was sent to me has ' in the time ('08:45), but I see no way of removing this without doing it manually.

Comment: That means that the times are text, not real date/time values. You can fix them with Text to Columns, by selecting the cells, then Data tab, Text To Columns, choosing Delimited then just clicking Next, then Finish.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you very much. Last question ... the formula returns 07:45, although I know the value is 06:45. It actually returns 07:45 no matter which date I try :P

Comment: Calculation set to manual?

Comment: Yes I have it set to manual, changing it does not help BTW.

Comment: Why do you have it set to manual? Your formulas won't calculate.

Comment: It is the way it was on this computer, haven't had any problems with it before. 
Anyway, changing it to automatic does nothing.

Comment: DATE is the name of an actual function.  At least in my version of excel.  As is TIME.  Try renaming your ranges to myDate and myTime or the like to distinguish them from the functions

Comment: Without seeing your workbook and the data, I couldn't say. Although it's not a great idea to use function names, it wouldn't effect the results. DATE is not the same as DATE().

Answer (score 0):

Alternative formula to the array. It should do the same thing:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,myTIME/((myDATE<=F4)*(myDATE>=F3)*(myTIME<=F6)*(myTIME>=F5)),1)
```

[image: POC]

Now this formula works with the assumption that your dates are actual excel dates and not text looking like a date.  Same goes for for time.  You can test it with the following formula:

```
ISNUMBER(E2)

or

ISTEXT(E2)
```

Where E2 is a cell containing a date or a time.  Excel stores dates as integers and times as decimals.  IF your information is stored as text, it is probably easier to convert them first then trying to apply your formula con the converted results.  you can convert withing your formula but it will tend to make the formula really ugly and long.

Comment: Well, I still got 07:45 >.< 

Thanks for trying to help me, I can't see what else to do so I will just give up and see if there is another way to do it. Worst case I need to go back to manually finding it by filtering etc.

Comment: best things to do is provide some sample data in your question.  Not the full range just a snippet of the information 5 rows or so and what your expected result is from that data.  We cant say why you are getting 07:45 without seeing what you are working with.